# Why does .net core encourage you to create interfaces for all of your dependencies?

Tags: asp.net-core, design-patterns

I am reading Microsoft's documentation on dependency injection, and I keep seeing the same pattern. The author will define some kind of service, create an interface for the service, and then add the interface to the service collection as an injectable dependency.

```
public class MyService : IMyService {
}
```

_

```
public interface IMyService {
}
```

Then in startup, in your ConfigureServices method, you register your service like this

```
services.AddScoped<IMyService>();
```

Then in a controller or another class, you will inject the interface as a dependency

```
public class SampleDataController : Controller {

    private readonly IMyService _service;

    public SampleDataController(IMyService service) {
       _service = service;
    }
```

It seems to me like you could just as easily do away with the interface. What are the benefits of defining your dependencies in this way?

Comment: So that you can change the dependencies easily. Read about the inversion of control .

Comment: @Zack ISSOIR I read microsofts documentation there as well. Microsoft writes about inversion control in an abstract way that I have trouble putting into context. Any additional clarity on the topic is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interfaces are a form of abstraction. When you define an interface, you're defining a contract that anything that claims to implement that interface must adhere to. Based on that then, you can substitute any implementation for any other implementation because they all adhere to that contract.

While there's many reasons why'd you want this, one of the primary ones is for testability. Let's say you have a class that depends on a particular database provider:

```
public class FooService
{
    private readonly SqlConnection _db;

    public FooService(SqlConnection db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
}
```

Because of the hard dependency on `SqlConnection` here, you can only ever use that specific provider. When unit testing this service, you'd have to connect to a real SQL Server instance, as there's no way to abstract this dependency. Then, you have an extra variable, as your test could fail because of an actual problem with your service or simply because there's some issue with the SQL Server connection. You'll never know.

Now, imagine you did this instead:

```
public class FooService
{
    private readonly IDbConnection _db;

    public FooService(IDbConnection db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
}
```

Now, you can pass anything that implements that interface. You could use `SqlConnection`, `OracleConnection`, etc. or even a completely mocked `IDbConnection` that stores data in-memory and returns canned responses.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, providing an interface for each dependency makes it easier to test your code, because you can mock away the implementation details? That is useful and concrete. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. That is one major benefit. There are others. Such as simply being able to easily stub in alternate providers. In the example code above, the interface frees you up to use any database provider that implements `IDbConnection`, allowing you to use this service with multiple different providers depending on the individual app or the environment you're deploying to, whereas using `SqlConnection` directly ties you to SQL Server period.

Comment: This is a great answer even though it only discusses one benefit of interfaces, please mark it as an answer if it cleared your confusion.